# Upstream GFCI trips regularly with new microwave use

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci, dryer

Moved into a new house in 2019 and installed a new microwave right off the bat. Found out that using the microwave (a new Samsung) trips the upstream GFCI maybe 5% of the time. Weird thing is that running our electric dryer seems to make the same GFCI trip 80% of the time. I say it's weird because the dryer and the microwave are on different legs/breakers. The same GFCI has never popped when only using the dryer or when using the dryer with other downstream devices.

I know the general concept behind GFCIs and neutral wires - that the outlets look for imbalances and neutrals are tied together with hot outside of the house - but that's about the extent. Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Comment: Any chance the "GFCI" might really be "AFCI"? Picture of the problem GFCI?

Comment: 120V or 230V? Location resp. climate? Is it a 5mA- or 30mA- GFCI? How many circuits (outlets and light circuits) does the GFCI protect? There must be no connection between Ground and Neutral downstream of the GFCI. What is the accumulated cable length between GFCI and all outlets/light circuits? Are there humidity problems in the house? Termites, rodents etc.?

Comment: So, running both the dryer *and* the microwave makes the GFCI trip semi-consistently?

Comment: You say "installed" a microwave? Like one with a vent over the stove/range? Those are normally on a dedicated circuit.   Depending upon your location can determine what version of the NEC is used.  You may or may not need GFCI or AFCI protection on a dedicated circuit for a microwave. You just have to check local codes.   But I think you have bigger issues...maybe a loose ground or neutral, maybe even a loose hot connection on your mains. Take voltage readings when not running the dryer and when running it.   That might help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts and suggestions around this. The GFCI protects maybe 3-4 downstream outlets, including the one the microwave plugs into. 120V. When I said installed, I truly meant just replacing the old one that was in there. I did add a 6ft extension cord for appliances between the outlet and the microwave. I know that's probably less than ideal, but I just can't reach the outlet otherwise and was hoping the super beefy cable wouldn't cause any voltage drop or relative differential.

Comment: Is it a 5mA or 30mA GFCI?

Comment: ...and is it a pure GFCI or a combination GFCI/AFCI? Photos would help to identify the problem.